# Source for B'Sha'ah Tovah on pregnancy?

Tags: sources-mekorot

Is there a source for the practice of using "B'Sha'ah Tovah" (בשעה טובה) as a well-wish on a pregnancy instead of the more common "Mazal Tov" (מזל טוב) used for most other occasions where a congratulations is due?

Comment: I think the first question should be is there a source for wishing anything at all (for a pregnancy)

Comment: Excellent point. MiYodeya etiquette: should I add that above and make it a two-part question? Or is it better to ask that as a separate, linked question?
(If the latter, it's all yours.)

Comment: My question was meant rhetorically